# Getting "java.sql.SQLException: setObject, Exception = For input string: "Pr""

Tags: java, plsql, callable-statement

I need to upload data from excelsheet to database.

I have used Apache POI concept to achieve this functionality.

```
    try {
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); // first sheet
        List excelData = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("sheet.getFirstRowNum() "+sheet.getFirstRowNum()+" sheet.getLastRowNum() "+sheet.getLastRowNum());
        int rowStart = Math.min(1, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
        int rowEnd = Math.max(10, sheet.getLastRowNum());
        for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
            Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
            if (r != null) {
                int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), 22);
                List cellData = new ArrayList();
                for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
                    Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

                    if (c == null) {
                        cellData.add(c);
                    } else {
                        cellData.add(c);
                    }
                }
                excelData.add(cellData);
            }
        }


        for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum < excelData.size(); rowNum++) {
            /*provide hssfEmployeeClass variables as null*/
            List list = (List) excelData.get(rowNum);
            HSSFCell[] EmployeeListCell = new HSSFCell[list.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    EmployeeListCell[i] = (HSSFCell) list.get(i);
                    //EmployeeListCell.set(i, ((HSSFCell) list.get(i)).toString());
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    EmployeeListCell[i] = (HSSFCell) null;
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    EmployeeListCell[i] = (HSSFCell) null;
                }
            }


            ArrayList EmployeeData = new ArrayList(list.size());
            long temp;
            java.sql.Date[] temp_date = new java.sql.Date[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < (EmployeeListCell.length-1); i++) {
                if(EmployeeListCell[i]==null)
                {}
                else if (EmployeeListCell[i].getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                    switch (EmployeeListCell[i].getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                        if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(EmployeeListCell[i])) {
                            EmployeeData.add(i,new java.sql.Date(EmployeeListCell[i].getDateCellValue().getTime()));
                        } else {
                            temp = (int) EmployeeListCell[i].getNumericCellValue();
                            //EmployeeData[i] = (Long.toString(temp));
                            EmployeeData.add(i,(Long.toString(temp)));
                        }
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                           EmployeeData.add(i,EmployeeListCell[i].getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (EmployeeListCell[i] != null) {
                    if (EmployeeListCell[i].getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(EmployeeListCell[i])) {
                           // EmployeeData[i] = (java.sql.Date) EmployeeListCell[i].getDateCellValue();
                           EmployeeData.add(i,new java.sql.Date(EmployeeListCell[i].getDateCellValue().getTime()));
                        } 
                        else
                        {    
                        temp = (int) EmployeeListCell[i].getNumericCellValue();
                        EmployeeData.add(i,(Long.toString(temp)));
                        }

                    }
                    if (EmployeeListCell[i].getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        System.out.println("Ith position "+i);
                        EmployeeData.add(i,EmployeeListCell[i].getStringCellValue());
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<EmployeeData.size();i++)
            {
            System.out.println("Employee data values"+ i + EmployeeData.get(i));
            }
            app=getApp();
            System.out.println("Return val is " + app.insertData(rowNum, EmployeeData));

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It will load the data from excel sheet in Employee Data Array list.

There is one java class, EmployeeObj is created which implements sqlData to pass the data through callable Statement.

```
public class EmployeeObj implements SQLData,Serializable {
public   long EMP_ID;               
public String FIRST_NM;    
public String MIDDLE_NM; 
public String DOJ;          
public String GENDER;   
public String STATUS;   
public String REPORTING_MGR;     
public String LAST_NM;
public String EMAIL_ID;
public String STREAM_ID;   
public String DESIGN_ID;   
public String EMP_LOCATION; 
public String GEO_CODE;   
public String EMP_NO; 
public String LEVEL_2_MGR;  
public String TENTATIVE_LAST_DAY;
private String sql_type="EMP_DATA_OBJ";
static int count=0;
public EmployeeObj() {
    super();
}
public EmployeeObj(String sql_type,Object[] empObj)
{
    this.sql_type = sql_type;
    count=count+1;
    System.out.println("empObj[1].toString(); "+ empObj[1].toString());
    this.EMP_NO=empObj[1].toString(); 
    this.EMP_ID=Long.parseLong(empObj[2].toString());               
    this.FIRST_NM=empObj[3].toString();    
    this.LAST_NM=empObj[4].toString();
    this.DOJ=empObj[5].toString();          
    this.GENDER=empObj[6].toString();   
    this.STATUS=empObj[7].toString();   
    this.REPORTING_MGR=empObj[9].toString();     
    this.LEVEL_2_MGR=empObj[11].toString();  
    this.EMAIL_ID=empObj[12].toString();
    this.STREAM_ID=empObj[13].toString();   
    this.DESIGN_ID=empObj[14].toString();   
    this.EMP_LOCATION=empObj[15].toString(); 
    this.GEO_CODE=empObj[16].toString();  
    try
    {
    this.TENTATIVE_LAST_DAY=empObj[17].toString();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException n)
    {
    System.out.println("Not a number in employee obj");
    }
}

@Override
public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Implement this method
    return sql_type;
}

@Override
public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Implement this method
    sql_type=typeName;
    this.EMP_ID=stream.readLong();               
    this.FIRST_NM=stream.readString();    
    //this.MIDDLE_NM=stream.readString();
    this.DOJ=stream.readString();  
    this.GENDER=stream.readString();  
    this.STATUS=stream.readString();   
    this.REPORTING_MGR=stream.readString();       
    this.LAST_NM=stream.readString();
    this.EMAIL_ID=stream.readString();
    this.STREAM_ID=stream.readString();
    this.DESIGN_ID=stream.readString();  
    this.EMP_LOCATION=stream.readString();
    this.GEO_CODE=stream.readString();
    this.EMP_NO=stream.readString();
    this.LEVEL_2_MGR=stream.readString();    
    this.TENTATIVE_LAST_DAY=stream.readString();
    }


@Override
public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Implement this method
    stream.writeLong(EMP_ID);
    stream.writeString(FIRST_NM);
    //stream.writeString(MIDDLE_NM);
    stream.writeString(DOJ);
    stream.writeString(GENDER);
    stream.writeString(STATUS);
    stream.writeString(REPORTING_MGR);
    System.out.println("write "+REPORTING_MGR);
    stream.writeString(LAST_NM);
    stream.writeString(EMAIL_ID);
    stream.writeString(STREAM_ID);
    stream.writeString(DESIGN_ID);
    stream.writeString(EMP_LOCATION);
    stream.writeString(GEO_CODE);
    stream.writeString(EMP_NO);
    stream.writeString(LEVEL_2_MGR);
    stream.writeString(TENTATIVE_LAST_DAY);

}
```

}

```
       CallableStatement pstmt =
           getDBTransaction().createCallableStatement("begin ?:= emp_dml.Main(?,EMP_OBJ_DT_ARR(?),?); end;",
                                                      0);
       EmployeeObj eob=null;
       Object[] obj = EmployeeD.toArray(new Object[EmployeeD.size()]);
       for(int i=0;i<EmployeeD.size();i++)
       {
           obj[i]=EmployeeD.get(i).toString();
           System.out.println("i "+i+" obj[i] "+obj[i]);
       }
       eob=new EmployeeObj("EMP_DATA_OBJ",obj);
       pstmt.setInt(2,row_id);
       pstmt.setObject(3, (Object) eob);
       pstmt.setString(4,user);
       pstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.BIGINT);

       try
       {
       pstmt.executeUpdate();
       }
       catch(SQLException e1)
       {
           System.out.println("ExecuteUpdate number format exception");
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
       System.out.println("After Update app insert");
       dbTransaction.commit();

   }
```

The type created for EmployeeData in pl/sql is:

```
  create or replace type EMP_OBJ_DT_ARR as table of EMP_DATA_OBJ; 

  create or replace TYPE EMP_DATA_OBJ AS OBJECT 
  (
  EMP_NO         VARCHAR2(10),  
  EMP_ID         NUMBER,      
  LAST_NM        VARCHAR2(100), 
  FIRST_NM       VARCHAR2(100), 
  DOJ            VARCHAR2(100),          
  GENDER         VARCHAR2(50),   
  STATUS         VARCHAR2(100),   
  REPORTING_MGR   NUMBER,          
  LEVEL_2_MGR     NUMBER,        
  EMAIL_ID        VARCHAR2(200), 
  STREAM_ID       VARCHAR2(100),     
  DESIGN_ID       VARCHAR2(100),   
  EMP_LOCATION    VARCHAR2(100),   
  GEO_CODE        VARCHAR2(100),   
  TENTATIVE_LAST_DAY CHAR(8));
```

Whenever I execute the code. I get exception

```
      java.sql.SQLException: setObject, Exception = For input string: "Pr"
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperImpl.invocationExceptionHandler(JDBCWrapperImpl.java:142)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:378)
at model.AppModuleImpl.insertData(AppModuleImpl.java:940)
at view.Parse_employee.upload(Parse_employee.java:176)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:46)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.event.ProxyEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(ProxyEvent.java:72)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:124)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1074)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:202)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Pr"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at oracle.sql.NUMBER.toBytes(NUMBER.java:1917)
at oracle.sql.NUMBER.stringToBytes(NUMBER.java:3448)
at oracle.sql.NUMBER.<init>(NUMBER.java:317)
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeNUMBER.toNUMBER(OracleTypeNUMBER.java:285)
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeNUMBER.toDatum(OracleTypeNUMBER.java:60)
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleType.toDatumInternal(OracleType.java:149)
at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toOracleArray(StructDescriptor.java:945)
at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toArray(StructDescriptor.java:1930)
at oracle.sql.STRUCT.<init>(STRUCT.java:165)
at oracle.sql.OracleSQLOutput.getSTRUCT(OracleSQLOutput.java:122)
at oracle.sql.STRUCT.toSTRUCT(STRUCT.java:875)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:13219)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:12597)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:13744)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:11812)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:260)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:363)
... 62 more
```

Here on first name I am getting Number Format exception. I am not converting it in any number format. So, Please suggest me on this.

Comment: You try to stuff a string that is not a number in a database field that is a number. You cannot do that.

Comment: First_nm is varchar2 field

Comment: And ` pstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.BIGINT);` is intended to do?

Comment: It's the return type from emp_dml.main(). The return type for this function is number.

Answer (score 0):

I have got little understanding that why I am getting numberFormatException.

As I have developed java class which implements SqlData.

SqlData has 2 methods which needs to be implemented in the class are:

```
 readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) 
 writeSQL(SQLOutput stream)
```

Here writeSQL will take data as stream. So whatever I will pass, it will be appended to stream.
Suppose I am passing data as

```
   id      name   age
   1       xyz    26
```

The datatype in java :

```
   id - Integer
   name - String
   age - Integer
```

In Pl/sql data type is

```
 id -number
 name -varchar2
 age -number
```

And If I will try to retrieve data in order of name,id and age (Eg: xyz 1 26)
then It will throw numberFormatException with sqlException. So need to pass in the same order, in which we have got.